# Why am I not able to see or click my navbar button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a button when my navbar collapses on smaller screen sizes. I can see the button exists in developer tools, however i cant see the hamburger icon, nor am i able to click the button to expand and collapse it. I am trying to acheive this using Bootstrap.

```
<nav class="col-6 col-md-6 navbar navbar-expand-sm">
    <button class='navbar-toggler ml-auto' type="button" data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navBarDropdown' aria-controls="navBarDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id='navBarDropdown'>
        <ul class=" navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="list-inline-item nav-item mr-2"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link hvr-float">Home</a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item nav-item mr-2"><a href="about.html" class="nav-link hvr-float">About</a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item nav-item mr-2"><a href="gallery.html" class="nav-link hvr-float">Gallery</a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item nav-item mr-2"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link hvr-float">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Two things: is bootstrap CDN for jquery and JS on the top of this HTML page? HTML is just a markup language, it needs JavaScript (or jquery) to be able to capture events. Second, this button will only be visible at certain screen sizes unless otherwise indicated.

Comment: CDNs for jquery _ popper.js & BootstrapJS should be at the **bottom** of your HTML page _ in the order I've listed them here

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your assistance. I have a script tag with the CDN link in on my page. I only want this to appear at the xs break point for bootstrap. It works as expected at all other screen sizes. When I reduce to size xs, the navbar disappears as id expect it to, i just cant actually see the hamburger button to press, even though its there (i can see it in dev tools).

Comment: Thanks @JustinRice  Ive fixed it now. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the jquery and bootstrap in correct order.After adding it,hamburger menu is working perfectly.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```